# How to count the number of banners/pages for dot indicators? I'm using smooth_page_indicator package available on pub.dev

Tags: flutter, widget, banner, flutter-widget, flutter-pageview

I have to return the number of pages in the PageView so that the value of 'count' in DotsAnimatedWidget->AnimatedSmoothIndicator automatically updates if the number of banners are increased or decreased. Is there any way to count the number of pages in the PageView or count the number of children? Should I approach a different way?
Link for the package used:
https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_page_indicator

```
class _BannerWidgetState extends State<BannerWidget> {
  int _pages = 0; 
  final _controller = PageController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 10),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
            child: Container(
              height: 140,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: PageView(
                controller: _controller,
                onPageChanged: ((val) {
                  setState(() {
                    _pages = val.toInt();
                  });
                }),
                children: const [
                  Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Banner 1',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Banner 2',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Banner 3',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                  
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        DotsIndicatorWidget(pages: _pages),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class DotsIndicatorWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const DotsIndicatorWidget({
    Key? key,
    required int pages,
  })  : _pages = pages,
        super(key: key);

  final int _pages;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned.fill(
      bottom: 18,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Row(
          //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
              activeIndex: _pages,
              count: 3,
              effect: const WormEffect(
                  spacing: 4.0,
                  activeDotColor: Colors.green,
                  dotColor: Colors.grey,
                  dotHeight: 8.0,
                  dotWidth: 8.0,
                  radius: 3,
                  type: WormType.normal),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable for children of PageView

```
List<Widget> _pages = [some Container]
int _currentIndex = 0;
```

And update it on onPageChanged()

```
onPageChanged: ((page) {
  setState(() {
    _currentIndex = page.toInt();
   });
}),
```

Count the number of pages in the PageView used: `_pages.length`

But I think, used package [smooth_page_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_page_indicator) is best way

Comment: Thanks man! Storing the pageView children under List<Widget> solved my problem.